# Recording macros with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, macros

What would be the most straight forward way to go about recording all actions performed on a page by the user so they can be played back?

This would primarily be for changing form values, replaying mouse clicks and triggering events.

I've looked for a plugin for this, but haven't found one.

Comment: Listen to all events sent to the body and store the event object and a timestamp. with an array of event objects and a timestamp, you should be able to execute the same list of events in order with the same amount of delay. You won't find a plugin that does this. keep in mind however that triggering events with jQuery will not perform some actions that happen when the event is triggered by the client.

Comment: This is not really possible. You will face security issues.

Comment: @Juno For catching events?

Comment: For replaying part. Read Kevin's comment.